# exec() command is not showing the output in stdout

Tags: javascript, node.js, exec, child-process

I am using exec command in order to understand it by installing the child_process node module.Below are the lines of code.
By looking at the output it shows that my `exec()` is not working as expected.

**exec.js**

```
console.log('1')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
console.log('2');
exec('node -v', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout', +stdout);
    console.log('stderr', +stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ', + error);
    }
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "exec",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "exec.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "child_process": "^1.0.2"
  }
  }
```

When running command `node exec.js` it displays the following output as follows

```
1
2
stdout NaN
stderr 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each of your `console.log` function calls, you have a `+` in front of each of your variable names. This tries to convert the value of the variable into the number. Remove the `+` in lines 5,6 and 8 and the code should run as expected.

Also it's better practice to use `console.error` when to output to  standard error.

```
console.log('1')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
console.log('2');
exec('node -v', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout', stdout);
    console.error('stderr', stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ', error);
    }
});
```